# Limit Google docs sharing with specific person or group

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-workspace, google-apps-script-addon

I want to limit my Google Doc sharing with specific users/groups in the organization using an editor add-on.

To achieve the same, I am thinking of two options:

1. Disable sharing and then share with specific users through the add-on.
2. Have a function triggered when doc is shared / share button is clicked.

Can someone help with any of the above approaches, or if the above is even possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: In Google Doc can we manipulate the sharing button functionality with editor add-on? Lets say, we want to disable the sharing button.  I hope this clears my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, though somewhat laborious. The steps to follow are:

1. Get familiar with the implementation of Google Drive file permissions in Apps Script(see below)
2. Adapt the [Quickstart for Google Docs Addon](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/docs/quickstart/translate) to your needs. Key points:

a) Define in the HTML file two sets of  elements, e.g. radio buttons - one set for the access type, one set for the permissions options.

```
    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="accessType" id="radio-access-anyone" value="DriveApp.Access.ANYONE">
    <label for="radio-access-anyone">Anyone can access</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="accessType" id="radio-access-domain" value="DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN">
    <label for="radio-access-domain">Domain members can access</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="permissionType" id="radio-permission-edit" value="DriveApp.Permission.EDIT">
    <label for="radio-permission-edit">Can edit</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="permissionType" id="radio-permission-view" value="DriveApp.Permission.VIEW">
    <label for="radio-permission-view">Can view</label>
    </div>
```

b) Implement in your HTML file a function that assigns the values of the radio buttons to an Apps Script variable and calls [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run):

```
function setPermission() {
...
        var accessType = $('input[name=accessType]:checked').val();
        var permissionType = $('input[name=permissionType]:checked').val();
        google.script.run    
... 
 }
```

c) Create in the `.gs` file a function that implements the `setSharing(accessType, permissionType)` method with the parameters retrieved through the radio buttons.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/

[2]https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#setSharing(Access,Permission)
[3]https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission